# Keep dropdown menu selected laravelcollective/html

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

I have a dropdown menu like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get']) !!}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                {!! Form::select('sort',[''=>'Choose Sort','asc'=>'Ascending','desc'=>'Descending'],null,['class'=>'form-control','onChange'=>'form.submit()']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="search"
                           value="{{ request('search') }}"
                           placeholder="Search name" name="search"
                           type="text" id="search"/>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I choose a item like "Ascending", my page reloaded and the dropdown menu return into "Choose Sort". I want to keep my selected value on dropdown menu.
How can I do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using AJAX to submit the changes

Comment: any way else? I don't really know about ajax so I don't think I can use it...

Comment: Could you provide more code ?

Comment: I updated my post. I have a form which are a dropdown menu to sort and a input to search. In search input, I use request('search') to keep my search value after submit but I don't know how to do it with dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just need to pass variable

**Change Your route as per your requirement**

> In Your View

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get','route' => 'document.sort']) !!}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                {!! Form::select('sort',[''=>'Choose Sort','asc'=>'Ascending','desc'=>'Descending'],isset($sortvalues) ? $sortvalues : '',['class'=>'form-control','onChange'=>'form.submit()']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" id="search"
                           value="{{ request('search') }}"
                           placeholder="Search name" name="search" value="{{ isset($searchvalues) ? $searchvalues : ''}}" 
                           type="text" id="search"/>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

> And my route

```
Route::any('/sort', 'DocDocumentController@sorDocument')->name('document.sort');
```

> And finnaly in Controller

```
public function sorDocument(Request $request)
    {
        $docDocuments = DocDocument::latest()->paginate(20,['*'],'documentPage');
        $searchvalues = $request->search;
        $sortvalues = $request->sort;
        $viewShare = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
        return view('docdocuments.index', compact($viewShare));
    }
```